# Android HTML5 Video only plays in full screen

Tags: android, html, video, android-fullscreen

I have an HTML5 video tag that works great in all browsers other than on Android.

When the video begins to play I can only hear the audio. I can only see the video if I click the full screen button.

The tablet is a Motorola Xoom with 4.1.2 and the Chrome app.

Code in a nutshell:

```
<div id='container'></div>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if(IsInMobileSafari()) {
                // ios video stuff
            } else if(IsInAndroid()) {
                $('#container').html(
                    '<video id="player" controls onended="Slide.Complete()">' +
                        '<source src="Slide' + $.getUrlVar('slide') + '.mp4">' +
                        '<source type="video/webm" src="Slide' + $.getUrlVar('slide') + '.webm">' +
                        '<source type="video/ogg" src="Slide' + $.getUrlVar('slide') + '.ogv">' +
                    '</video>'
                );
                $('#player')[0].play();
            } else {
                // other video stuff
            }

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried running it in the native browser?

Comment: Yes, the native browser just loops the loading animation after I click play and never does anything else. The native browser is not a requirement though. We have since tried it in a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 and it works properly on that device.

Comment: I know its old post but i have same issue! Did you find amy solution for it?

Comment: @user1788736 - No. I suspect it was an issue with that specific device. It had issues playing videos on other websites as well. We haven't had the same issue on any other device model since.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if still needed after 7 years but
use `webkit-playsinline` attribute for android browsers
and just `playsinline` attribute for iOS browsers
source : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)